# asp:HyperLink dynamic ID

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink

ref: [Dynamic Control ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783784/creating-controls-in-asp-with-dynamic-ids)

Does anyone have a working example of creating the ID property of a hyperlink dynamically?

I have a repeater with multiple hyperlinks drawn (3 per row for a survey). I would like to change the image of the hyperlink clicked. The repeater is created from its bound datasource. Cant get it working

EDIT:I used your example and it does change the image, however it changes all the ID="HappyLink" items instead of the one selected.

```
    // if the happy emoticon was clicked
    if (this.Request.QueryString["hyperlink"] == "HappyLink")
    {
        HyperLink happylink = e.Item.FindControl("HappyLink") as HyperLink;

        if (happylink != null)
        {
            happylink.ImageUrl = "~/images/happy_selected.jpg";
        } // if (happylink != null)
    } // if (this.Request.QueryString["hyperlink"] == "HappyLink")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to worry about dynamic IDs. The `Repeater` control sorts out the IDs for you, you don't need to care what they are.

If you mean that each `Hyperlink` is an image, then you need to handle the [`ItemDataBound`](http://preview.library.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound(v=VS.100).aspx) event of the `Repeater`. In the markup, you give the `Hyperlink` an ID. In the `ItemDataBound` event handler, you use the `FindControl` method on the `Item` object you get from the event argument, passing the ID of the `Hyperlink`. This will give you the actual hyperlink control. Then just set the image.

For example:

```
void Repeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
   HyperLink hyperLink = e.Item.FindControl("HappyLink") as HyperLink;
   if (hyperLink != null)
   {
      // do something with the hyperlink
   }
}
```

In the `FindControl` method, you just use the ID you set in the markup. The use of `e.Item` ensures you get the hyperlink from the right row of the repeater.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have the 3 hyperlink controls (HappyLink,OkLink,FailLink) in the repeater and they all loop accordingly. However, the ID that I give them is the same for all the databound items that I have. I understand that the ID changes to something like Repeater1_ctl01_HappyLink. How do I use the FindControl method to find the 5th row's first icon when clicked? e.g. Repeater1_ctl05_HappyLink. I come from a PHP background, so please bear with me

Comment: @Thomas: I've added an example, hopefully this makes things clearer.